Weather data from BigQuery to LookerStudio
I've added my noaa_global_forecast to looker studio using a BigQuery public data-set. I've been trying to do simple stuff like creating a chart with dimensions [creation_time] and [geography] and as  metric [temperature_2m_above_fround].
The problem is that I cannot get the [geography] dimension to work. I've tried many configurations and nothing worked. I'm not new to Looker Studio but I still can't find a solution
